# Mathematical induction and the counting function on $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$

Tags: induction

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be a finite field of order $p$  and $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ be a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. We consider the distance $\lVert \cdot \rVert:\mathbb{Z}_p^2\to \mathbb{Z}_p$ defined by $\lVert {x}\rVert:=x_1^2+x_2^2$, where ${x}=(x_1,x_2)$. Suppose that $E\subset \mathbb{Z}_p^2$ and consider the function $$\nu_n(t_1,\dots,t_n)=\#\{(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})\in E^{n+1}: \lVert x_i-x_{i+1}\rVert=t_i \ \text{for}\ i=1,\dots n\}.$$

I claim that $$\nu_n(t_1,\dots,t_n)=\sum \limits_{x_{n+1}\in E}((\dots((E*S_{t_1})E*S_{t_2})\dots)E*S_{t_n})(x_{n+1}),$$ where by $*$ I denote the convolution $f*g:\mathbb{Z}_p^2\to \mathbb{C}$ of $f,g:\mathbb{Z}_p^2\to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $(f*g)(m)=\sum \limits_{x\in \mathbb{Z}_p^2}f(x)g(m-x).$

I checked that this formula is valid for $n=1,2,3,4$. But I cannot prove it via induction, i.e. I have issues with induction step.

I'd be very thankful if someone can show the solution please.

**EDIT:** We use $S_t$ to denote the sphere of radius $t$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$: thus $S_t=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}_p^2: \lVert x\rVert=t\}.$ $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ and $E^{n+1}$ is just a Cartesian product of $E$ with itself $(n+1)$ times. By $E(x)$ and $S_t(x)$ I denoted indicator functions of $E$ and $S_t$.

Comment: You forgot to define $S_{t_i}$ and $E^{n+1}$.  Also, $E$ is a subset and a function?

Comment: @BrianHopkins, ohh sorry I forgot to define it. Please look at my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y\in E$, define
$$
\mu_n(t_1,\ldots,t_n,y)=\#\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in E^n\colon \|x_i-x_{i+1}\|=t_i,
$$
where $x_{n+1}$ is taken to be $y$.

Then your $\nu_n(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ is just $\sum_{y\in E}\mu_n(t_1,\ldots,t_n,y)$. It's easy to see that for $z\in E$,
$$
\mu_{n+1}(t_1,\ldots,t_n,t_{n+1},z)=
\sum_{y\in E, z-y\in S_{t_{n+1}}}\mu_n(t_1,\ldots,t_n,y).
$$
That is,
$$
\mu_{n+1}(t_1,\ldots,t_n,t_{n+1},z)=
\big([\mu_n(t_1,\ldots,t_n,\cdot)\mathbf 1_E(\cdot)]*S_{t_{n+1}}\big)(z).
$$
Hence by induction,
$$
\mu_n(t_1,\ldots,t_n,z)=
(\cdots((\mathbf 1_E*S_{t_1})\mathbf 1_E)*S_{t_2})\cdots\mathbf 1_E)*S_{t_n}(z).
$$
Your formula then follows.

Comment: Can you explain the formula after "Hence by induction"? Intuitively this is true, but cannot get it. I guess here you implicitly using almost the similar statement of my question. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The formula that precedes the sentence “Hence by induction” is the inductive step. The point of my answer is that it is easy to write out the relationship between $\mu_n$ and $\mu_{n+1}$, while there is no simple relationship between $\nu_n$ and $\nu_{n+1}$.

Comment: A simpler, but completely analogous issue arises if you want to study a sequence $x_n=u.A^n.v$ (where $u$ and $v$ are vectors and $A$ I’d s matrix). This sequence has no nice one step recurrence formula, but $y_n=A^n.v$ does satisfy the simple relationship $y_{n+1}=Ay_n$.

Comment: If the formula that precedes the sentence "Hence by induction" is the inductive step then how the formula after sentence "Hence by induction" was obtained? Sorry I am a bit confused. What statement are you proving by induction?

Comment: The statement being proved by induction is the statement following “Hence by induction“; the inductive step precedes “Hencd by induction”

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Prof. Quas! I highly appreciate it. I've gotten some conclusions from your answer: the function $\mu_n$ is a bit different than $\nu_n$ in this sense: in $\mu_n$ you are fixing the last vertex $y$ and then you are counting over the vertices. If you sum over all $y\in E$ you get $\nu_n$. I was trying to obtain some relation between $\nu_n$ and $\nu_{n+1}$ but I failed. However for $\mu_n$ and $\mu_{n+1}$ we can write the relation between them. Impossibility of writing relation for $\nu_n$ and $\nu_{n+1}$ comes from the fact that the vertices are random (not fixed).

Comment: Is my understanding correct? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I would say the reason there isn't such a simple recurrence for $\nu_n$ is that the number of elements of $E$ that you can reach with a jump of norm $t_{n+1}$ depends on which element of $E$ you are at at stage $n$.

Comment: The sentence "you can reach with a jump of norm $t_{n+1}$ depends on which element of $E$ you are at a stage $n$" sounds not so clear to me. Can you clarify it please?

Comment: I mean the number of places you are allowed to go to at stage n+1 depends on where you are at stage n.